# Node connect add CORS header

Tags: node.js, http, cors, http-headers, node.js-connect

I have this code.

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic("public")).listen(80, function(){
});
```

I'd like to add cross origin policy headers to all responses.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [cors module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) that you can use.

```
var http = require('http');
var cors = require('cors');
var connect = require('connect');

var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var app = connect();

app.use(cors());
app.use(serveStatic("public"));

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

By the way, is there a reason that you don't use express?

Comment: Connect is based on express and there are lots of reason not to use express. express is dead and there are no active development going on !

Comment: @WitVault connect is based on express?  I can't find any reference in the package.json about express: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/package.json Did they announce something about express and that is will be deprecated? Do you have a source?

Comment: Sorry It was reverse actually. Express was using connect. But with express 4 connect was not used in express. Creator of both is TJ and TJ sold express to a company StrongLoop.
Read this reddit post https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/4cjuf7/is_express_dead_what_do_you_use_instead/

Also 

https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2844

Comment: @WitVault This is what I was remembering that express was based on connect. I wasn't aware that they 've dropped it on express 4 though. Then I found the same express issue that you 've posted. There are sooo many things going on that we can't follow everything :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) npm package to enable cors support.

Installation:

```
$ npm install cors
```

Usage:

```
var app = connect();
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors());
```